# This SQL code works when being executed in SMMS but not when called via ExecuteNonQuery() in .Net why?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I suppose this is a very minor thing, but I seem to not see it.
I have a script that sets up some views and indices in an already existing database (column and table details should not matter for this question...)

```
USE <dbname>

GO
CREATE VIEW [dbo].View1_
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT
      [someTable].[Id]
  FROM [dbo].[someTable]
  WHERE [dbo].[someTable].[Str] != N'someString'

GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX someTable_Index1
    ON [dbo].View1_(ID)

GO
...
```

Now this executes fine if I run it from SQL Server Management Studio for example.
But I want it to be setup when a certain web site is called; I saved the script above in a folder that is inside an MVC4-Project and I produced the following snippet:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SomeConnectionString"].ToString();

string scriptCommand = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Models/View1_IndexedViews.sql"));

using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.CommandText = scriptCommand;

        try
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(SqlException e)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

But now when I trigger that call, an exception gets thrown here saying

```
"Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.\r\n'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.\r\nIncorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
```

Can someone give me a hint, what am I missing here? I know that message `CREATE VIEW must be the first statement`, but that should normally be eliminated by preceding `GO`s before each `CREATE VIEW`, this message also seems to indicate it does not like the `WITH SCHEMABINDING`, but why is that exactly?

Any hints/help appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The database doesn't have any `go` command, that is only used in Management Studio (and some similar tools) to separate batches.

In some cases you can just remove the `go` commands and run it as a single batch. Otherwise you need to separate them into several database calls.

If the syntax is as predictable as in the example, then you can just split on `"\r\nGO\r\n"` and execute each string.

Comment: good point, didn't know that about `GO`yet, here is the reference http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx so if I want to batch create several views I have to split it up right?

Comment: ah just read your edit about splitting by `GO`, very good input, thanks!